# Javascript Last character missing on OnKeyPress event

Tags: javascript, dom-events, onkeypress

```
function h(x)
{
    alert(x);
}

<input onkeypress=h(this.value) type=text>
```

When I press 'a' alert empty
When I press 'b' after 'a' =>ab alert only 'a' and I want 'ab'
When I type 'abcd' it alert 'abc' only and I want 'abcd'

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
var unicode=e.keyCode? e.keyCode : e.charCode;
typing = document.getElementById('textbox').value + String.fromCharCode(unicode);
```

Comment: crap. Your question and your answer. biased.

Answer (score 26):

your event fires **before** letter is registered. you should use **[onkeyup event](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeyup.asp)**. It kicks-in after you release key

Comment: FYI: `onkeyup` will not register multiple presses if the user holds a key down

Answer (score 4):

Javascript:

```
function h(x) 
{
   alert(x); 
}
```

HTML Code:

```
<input onkeyup=h(this.value) type=text>
```