# How does $timeout fix this?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

My keypress event handler is always one keystroke behind and somehow `$timeout` fixes this.

```
<body ng-controller="myController">
  <form>
    <input ng-keypress="handleKeypress($event)" />
  </form>
</body>
```

Controller:

```
myapp.controller('myController', function($scope, $timeout){    
    $scope.handleKeypress = function(ev){

      console.log(ev.target.value); //always one keystroke behind

      //$timeout(function(){console.log(ev.target.value);}); //works!         
    };
});
```

Why is `$timeout` necessary and why/how does it work?

I understand that with the `keypress` event the character hasn't yet been inserted into the DOM, but I'm confused because the Hello World example at [angularjs.org](http://angularjs.org) responds before a key is released.

(Their example doesn't use a custom event handler, but clearly Angular is updating the model before the `keyup` event, so I'd like understand more about doing this in a custom event handler.)

`event.which` is available on `keypress` and `keydown`, and I thought perhaps Angular might be using `String.fromCharCode()`, but I don't see anything in the Angular source to this effect.

Comment: $timeout forces a digest to happen. Although ng-keypress should also trigger a digest, so I'm not sure why it's one stroke behind. Is there anymore code you're not posting?

Comment: I think it's a problem with onkeypress event, check these: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9349587/javascript-onkeypress-event-fires-but-input-text-value-is-incorrect , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5340751/javascript-last-character-missing-on-onkeypress-event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$timeout` allows for your function to run in the next cycle, after the value has been added to the field at the end of the current cycle.  Basically, with `$timeout`, you are telling it to wait, and while it waits `ev.target.value` gets updated.

As far as the example. Angular is running dirty checks looking for things that change on UI events, that is how it knows to update its value.  Its happening after the keypress event.  The dirty checks are timeout based.  You can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/TheSharpieOne/V6p9M/1/ that the $scope is not updated when your function runs. Change the log to an alert and you see the DOM is not updated either.

If you are trying to avoid that `$timeout` call you can use the `ngChange` event.  Unlike the normal `onChange` (which fires on `blur`), `ngChange` will fire every time the value is changed, such as a keystroke.

http://jsfiddle.net/TheSharpieOne/V6p9M/

Comment: I have a vague notion of the browser event loop -is that what's meant by "cycle"?

Comment: Yes.  Sorry for the difference in terminology. To me [in my mind] the event loop is the process and cycle is one instance/run-through of the event loop.